Multiple tags for docker image in VS 2022
I'd like to tag a image (dockerfile build from VS 2022) with :latest and a version number (ideally taken from the MSBuild property VersionPrefix). Is this possible within VS?
I already tried to set the DockerfileBuildArguments property, but VS seems to push only the tag specified in the .pubxml file (PublishImageTag).
TIA
Michael

The .pubxml file is itself an MSBuild file that is Imported into the project file. If the VersionPrefix property is defined without any Condition in multiple places, then the last definition seen is the value that will be used. If you don't want a redefinition, add a Condition as shown in "MSBuild best practices" -- e.g. <VersionPrefix Condition="'$(VersionPrefix)' == ''">1.2.3</VersionPrefix>.

Have you read DockerfileTag in this document:Properties for Dockerfile projects?
